# How to control JavaScript debugger

Tags: javascript, debugging, frontend, trace, control-flow

I am trying to trace some JavaScript to figure out what is triggering the hiding and showing of a certain element. However, as soon as the debugger executes out of the block in which I placed it, it starts going through all sorts of plugins and what I am assuming is JavaScript built into the browser (the files labelled VM).

[image: chrome dev tools sources]

I have tried blackboxing these scripts to no use. I tried to include a pattern that blackboxes any file with "vendor" or "VM" in the filename, but neither has worked.

[image: chrome dev tools blackbox settings]

As soon as the debugger steps in to one of these files, it takes thousands and thousands of steps to complete the click event, making the debugging process useless. How can I keep the debugger from stepping into these files?

Comment: Well if you are using Chrome then there are the "Step into next function call", :"Step over next function call" and the "Step out of current function call" buttons. Maybe try using some of those?

Comment: Is just disabling the plugins an option?